# for loop and user input in JES

Tags: python, jes

I have a function

```
def decreaseRed(picture, amount):
    for p in getPixels(picture):
        value = getRed(p)
        setRed(p, value * amount)
```

I would like the function to ask the user to input the amount and then calculate that amount.  I know this is probably simple but it has me stumped and I cant find the answer in a book.

Thank you

Comment: raw_input is the function you can use to get user input

Answer (score 0):

From the [JES Guide](http://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs101b1/jes/#Taking%20User%20Input):

```
amount = requestNumber("Enter Amount:")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider:

```
amount = requestInteger("Amount: ")
```

or

```
amount =requestIntegerInRange("Amount in range min-max:", min, max)
```

if you you want to constrain the possible values.